# How to link variable group to azure pipeline using Rest API?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any possibility to add variables group to Azure pipeline using Rest API?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Show in detail what you want to achieve, what you mean by _variable group_, show what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. PLease read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it is now, you will probably get no answers at all or perhaps someone will answer simply `"Maybe"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a Rest API to add a variable group, [Variablegroups - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/DGDemo/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Body:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "key1": {
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "key2": {
      "value": "value2",
      "isSecret": true
    }
  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "TestVariableGroup1",
  "description": "A test variable group"
}
```

Comment: The question was how to Link the variable group not to create one